How to redirect user to "Clear Data" setting page
When user click button I want them to be then redirected to "Clear Data" page (3rd page in attached image).
By this code I get first screen (see image), I want to open the 3rd page directly.
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.Settings$ManageApplicationsActivity"));
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_APPLICATION_PREFERENCES);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.android.chrome"));

// Verify that the intent resolves to an activity
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
    startActivity(intent);
}


